# Do i need miners for my own cryprocurrency which is based on ethereum?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have a question. Do i need to find miners for my own cryprocurrency which is based on ethereum or ethereum will provide them for their fee to let transactions with my currency be accepted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need miners specifically for your Ethereum-powered coin/token. Transfers of your token happen via transactions to your smart contract. Those transactions, like all Ethereum transactions, will be mined by Ethereum miners.

Comment: btw, miners have a stable profit by mining ethereum. And they have a reward in ETC. My coin will not cost so much like ETH but gonna be mined with it as you said. Profit from mining depends on currency cost. How ethereum handle a reward for miners who are mining a lot of coins which has a low cost and they are powered by ethereum?

Comment: The miners get paid in ETH. It doesn't matrer what the transactions are.